# Why is the python index method not appending indexes?

Tags: python-3.x

I have two lists. I am trying to create a third list that holds the index of matched values between the two.

```
>>>reason1[:5]
['S02F00064', 'S02F00492', 'S08F00085', 'S04F00198B', 'S07F00007']

>>>caids[:5]
['A11F00111', 'F00S00999', 'S00F00001', 'S00F00004', 'S00F00015']

caccnomatch=caccdex=[]
for cc in reason1:
    if cc:
        try: caccdex.append(caids.index(cc.upper()))
        except: caccnomatch.append(cc.upper())
```

caccnomatch is suppose to hold the actual value that wasn't matched.
caccdex is supposed to be a list of numerical values corresponding to indexes of matched values in caids.

This is the output from caccdex:

```
>>> caccdex[:5]
[176, 317, 1446, 'S04F00198B', 1175]
```

Why am I getting a value in the list of indexes?

Comment: `caccnomatch=caccdex=[]` **does not** create two separate lists, it creates *two references to a single list*.

Comment: To further explain @jonrsharpe 's answer, appending to `caccdex` and appending to `caccnomatch` is doing the same thing, since they point to the exact same list. To prove this, you can try something like `caccdex is caccnomatch` and you should get `True`.

Comment: Of course! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `caccdex` and `caccnomatch` are aliases of each other. They are two names pointing to the same piece of memory. The statement `caccnomatch=caccdex=[]` makes one spot in memory and has both names point to it. Since they are linked like this, when you modify one, it also changes the other. The way you can check for this is `caccnomatch is caccdex`, which returns `True` if they are the same spot in memory, and `False` otherwise.

[More information about aliases](http://henry.precheur.org/python/copy_list)